# Multidimensional array model Django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

TLDR: trying to send a 2d array with django rest and it fails, why?

So here is my situation. I am creating a ingest tool to take in data, that is created by someone else. Part of this data is a 2d array or a list of lists, whatever strikes your fancy. Something like this being a list of lists of floats in this case

`Data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`

I am trying to use a Django rest service to do this because thats what i have been using for everything else i have done. Anyway this data type is given to me in a json format along with other datatypes Which i will show as well. On the model side of this i have a model of the main `dataType` that `data` would go into which looks like this

```
class dataType(models.Model):
  data = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True),
                              null=True), null=True)  
  data1 = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True),
                               null=True)
  ...
  other data
```

Now `data` is the one i am having issues with. `data1` will work fine as long as its just singular dimensional array(list). when i run the code with this i get an error saying this `Expected a list of items but got type \\"str\\"."]}'` even though i am sending it a list. It gets a 400 for this vary reason. Here is what the json code would look like.

```
"dataType": [
  {
    "otherData": stuff                                
    "data": [
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ]
  }
]
```

Just as side not before anyone asks, no i cannot change the data from a 2d array, it has to stay like that, if it were up to me i would change it.

Another side note, i have attempted using just one arrayfield like `data1` with the 2d array stuff, it returns back a 201 BUT on the rest side when i go to localhost:8000/api/v3/dataType it gives me a 500 error and complains and says something along the lines of looking for a string or float but received a list.

UPDATE: concerning the last side note, i have found this does work but it converts my 2d array into one giant single array so this is still not what i want, i need my 2d array to stay as a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was something very dumb. I have multiple ingestors all using this code but it seems that the multidimensional array threw that for a loop. What fixed my problem was in the request call. What i had originally was this:

```
response = requests.post(data_endpoint, data=temp, verify=False)
```

`temp` being the json formatted data. What fixed my problem was specifically doing a dumps on it and choosing the media type.

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(data_endpoint, data=json.dumps(temp), verify=False, headers=headers)
```

Again i am not sure why the multi dimensional array forces my hand in this situation but that's what fixed my problem